# Is it possible to declare a function which takes Win32 event HANDLE as a parameter in idl 3.0 file?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am trying to author a set of APIs for my customer.

They need a function which takes Win32 event HANDLE as a parameter for them to wait event via WaitForSingleObject().

However, I cannot find the correct data types for this HANDLE type.

Is it possible to use Win32 event HANDLE in idl 3.0 file?

Comment: IDL 3 supports the Windows Runtime, and there is no `HANDLE` type in the Windows Runtime, in part because not all languages have a way of using it. (There is no `WaitForSingleObject` in JavaScript, for example.) The Windows Runtime way would be to provide an event source. The recipient would subscribe to the Windows Runtime event. When the event is raised, recipient can then do whatever they would have done when the `HANDLE` was signaled under your handle-based design. Alternatively, you could provide an `IAsyncAction` that completes when the `HANDLE` would have been signaled.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you! I will try Windows Runtime event!

Comment: For reference, these are the supported [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#types) in MIDL version 3.

Comment: @RaymondChen It works! Can you reply and then I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Feel free to flesh out my quick sketch into an answer and accept it. I don't need the imaginary points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Raymond's comment, the MIDL 3.0 doesn't support `HANDLE` type and he recommended to use Windows Runtime event instead.

I developed Windows Runtime event following Microsoft's [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-events).